# Is azure IOT Hub direct method and device twin supported in UWP application?

Tags: azure, uwp, device, azure-iot-hub

I am planning to implement iot hub device management feature to reboot and firmware update on our device.

That device using windows 10 IOT core OS and it's firmware is develop in UWP application.

I am not sure that this feature support available for UWP app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work with a device connection oriented protocol to the Azure IoT Hub such as AMQP and MQTT.

The following screen snippets shows a sample Blinky (UWP App) as a MQTT Device connected to the Azure IoT Hub:

Visual Studio 2017:
[image: VS2017]

Device Explorer to invoke a direct method on the Device:
[image: Device Explorer]

and finally, the following screen snippet shows a target RPi3B with a Windows IoT Core (in this sample version: v.10.0.17133.1):
[image: RPI3]

and Windows Device portal:
[image: portal]

Comment: thanks for solution. I tried to implement direct method sample with uwp app. But at runtime it generate exception in method "Client.SetMethodHandlerAsync(". Exception detail is "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client v1.4.2, what is yours?

Comment: @Krishna_K_Systematix, you can try to change the min version of target to 16299 in you solution property.